# feature andoid module - not permite to use apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

Tags: java, android, swift, react-native, kotlin

i am trying to create a feature in android, but i get the next error

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project
>   C:\Users\wilso\OneDrive\Documents\retrofit_system\retrofit_system
>
> > Configure project :feature:webview WARNING: The com.android.feature plugin is deprecated and will be removed by the end of 2019. Please
> >     switch to using dynamic-features or libraries. For more information on
> >     converting your application to using Android App Bundles, please visit
> >     https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration
> >     WARNING: The com.android.feature plugin is deprecated and will be
> >     removed by the end of 2019. Please switch to using dynamic-features or
> >     libraries. For more information on converting your application to
> >     using Android App Bundles, please visit
> >     https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':feature:webview'.
>
>   > 'kotlin-android' expects one of the Android Gradle plugins to be applied to the project:    * android       * com.android.application       *
>   >     android-library       * com.android.library       * com.android.test      *
>   >     com.android.feature       * com.android.dynamic-feature       *
>   >     com.android.instantapp
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 383ms

The gradle is the next

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {

    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'RtlEnabled'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

I searched any solution, but i can't get nothing,

If I use the next gradle, it is functioned

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.co.webview"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

but i don't want to create a application, because i want to create a feature

Comment: "The com.android.feature plugin is deprecated and will be removed by the end of 2019." I'm pretty sure we're in 2020.

Comment: yes, i understood the log, but i can't find the solution to create a feature

Comment: I think this [article](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration) might help you.

Comment: i done a test, my problem was fixed, but i don't understand why the next label affects the build 'apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'. if i remove it, my app builds. someone knows what is the use the next apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Comment: `kotlin-android` expects to find an android plugin as shown by the stacktrace. Most likely the `com.android.feature` plugin was removed so there's no android plugin when you build. `kotlin-android` is just the equivalent of the `kotlin` gradle plugin, but for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done a test and it was functioned

if i use the next gradle, my app builds

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {

    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'RtlEnabled'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {



}
```

but if i use the next gradle, it is not functioned

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {

    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'RtlEnabled'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {




}
```

the difference between the first and  the second is apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Answer (score 0):

changed to

new plugin: com.android.dynamic-feature